# Is Intel Server board sh3200 with xeon x3220 good for virtualization?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization, xeon

I am wondering if the sh3200 and xeon x3220 will run virtualization well.

I have this server running and it's fine but I want to throw on some virtual servers.

My plan is to run linux/ubuntu with virtualbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtualBox has no special requirements. Although the right CPU helps speed things up, of course. That being said, your [Xeon X3220](http://ark.intel.com/products/28034), although relatively dated, supports Intel VT-x.

Comment: I notice that some of the newer processors support vt-d and ept. Do those features make a big difference? The systems I am virtualizing are under very very low loads, mostly idle. But, I plan to run about 5-6 virtualized systems all at the same time, though each has very low loads.

Comment: @user277244 - Yes they make a difference.  It entirely depends on your need.  Research each feature before you make a decision.